# Library Not loading in Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

My library Class in common/auth/auth_manager.php folder :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Auth_manager {
public function __construct() {
    $this->allow_dev_login = TRUE;
    $this->_ci =& get_instance();
    $this->_ci->load->spark('flexi-auth/1.5.0/');
}}
```

My controller :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class Contacts extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    echo "string";
    $this->load->library('auth/auth_manager');
}
```

In the above code the string before loading the library is working . But after loading the page is just blank . Have to use the functions from those libraries . If i use the below code

`$this->auth_manager->register();`

Getting the error property not defined .

Answer (score 0):

your library file at wrong place

According to Codeigniter standard Keep your library in `application/libraries/` directory then you can load library

```
$this->load->library('auth_manager');
```

For more follow [here](http://weblint4u.com/create-custom-library-in-codeigniter/)

or official docs :- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: but we can load the libraries in the common folder directly ryt?

Comment: nope this will not a library it's will be simple class file. use codeigniter standard

Answer (score 0):

`$this->load->library();` method is finding library in `/application/libraries` or `/system/libraries` folders, if you want to load library from another location then register third party folder path

`$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'common/auth/');`

and then user load library method

`$this->load->library('auth_manager');`